# missing required architecture armv7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

i use xcode with libsqlite3.dylib for sqlite , but when i compile to device the following error arise :

```
Ld /Users/user1319/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Directory-app normal armv7
    cd /Users/user1319/Desktop/app/app

    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/user1319/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app_Directory-bnkhohrmxdhrusarswxeqvxlljct/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos -F/Users/user1319/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnkhohrmxdhrusarswxeqvxlljct/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos -filelist "/Users/user1319/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnkhohrmxdhrusarswxeqvxlljct/Build/Intermediates/app Directory.build/Distribution-iphoneos/app.build/Objects-normal/armv7/app.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker / -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -lsqlite3 -lsqlite3.0 -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/user1319/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnkhohrmxdhrusarswxeqvxlljct/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/app.app/app

ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMStatement reset] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMResultSet next] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase changes] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase(FMDatabaseAdditions) validateSQL:error:] in FMDatabaseAdditions.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase open] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase openWithFlags:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMResultSet next] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_next_stmt", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase close] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_threadsafe", referenced from:
      +[FMDatabase isThreadSafe] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase lastInsertRowId] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase close] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMStatement close] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase(FMDatabaseAdditions) validateSQL:error:] in FMDatabaseAdditions.o
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet stringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet UTF8StringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet longForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet longLongIntForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet columnCount] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet setupColumnNames] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet setupColumnNames] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet columnNameForIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase lastErrorMessage] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMResultSet next] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet stringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dateForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet columnIndexIsNull:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet UTF8StringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet objectForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      ...
  "_sqlite3_libversion", referenced from:
      +[FMDatabase sqliteLibVersion] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase lastErrorCode] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMResultSet hasAnotherRow] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet intForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase close] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet doubleForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_data_count", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet resultDict] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But the project compiled successfully to simulator , the error happen when i compiled the project to real device .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i found the problem :  libsqlite3.dylib that i used compiled for armv6 not 7 , so i just download xcode dmg file 4.3 and extract the lib from it .

Answer (score 37):

Look if  libsqlite3.dylib is added to all your targets.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you receiving this message while validating an app archive in Xcode 4.5.1 - there is a known issue preventing Xcode from properly handling product names contain non-alpha characters. That said, the issue went away after I **take all non-alpha characters out** of the `Product Name` build setting.